# C - Output the longest line from terminal input

Tags: c

Currently practicing *The C Programming Language* book of BRIAN W KERNIGHAN DENNIS M. RITCHIE, and the following program should output the longest word. I cannot see what is wrong in my program, would appreciate if one help me to detect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getLine(char line[], int maxLine);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main() {
  int len;
  int max;
  char line[MAXLINE];
  char longest[MAXLINE];

  max = 0;
  while((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
    if(len > max) {
      len = max;
      copy(longest, line);
    }
    if(max > 0)
      printf("Longest line is: %s ", longest);
    return 0;
  }
}

int getLine(char line[], int maxLine) {
  int c, i;
  // satir icin ongorulen maksimum harf sayisi asilmadikca
  // we birsonraki karakter de EOF veya newline degilse
  for(i = 0; (i < maxLine - 1) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'); ++i) {
    line[i] = c;
  }
  if(c == '\n') {
    line[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  line[i] = '\0';
  return i;

}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
  int i;
  i = 0;
  while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: `I cannot see what is wrong in my program`..please show your efforts..what did you try for debugging?

Comment: I compiled it and run? I don't know what I should do further fur such a basic C program :)

Comment: In order to debug simple programs like this, you should read it and analyze each step (maybe print out variables in some points) to find the problem.

Comment: Poor man's debugging consists in placing `printf`s in strategic places. On Windows I find the freely available Visual Studio very helpful for debugging. Other integrated development environments like eclipse have similar debugging frontends. With gcc and an editor you must learn gdb commands which is less comfortable but equally powerful.

Comment: (Advanced) Corner cases: Code has trouble when `maxLine < 2` as `c` is uninitialized in `if(c == '\n')` (suggest `int c  = 0;`) and `line[i]` is UB with pathological case if `maxLine < 1` (suggest an initial `if (maxline < 1) return 0;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this part of your code:

```
  max = 0;
    while((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
      if(len > max) {
        len = max;
        copy(longest, line);
    }
```

`max` is `0` at the beginning. in the if condition, you assign `len` to be `max` which is `0`. There is also another problem, the program will return 0 after the first iteration of your `while` because you put `return 0` inside it.

Comment: yes, it looks issue in while as Mohammad said, you could try  modifing like   `while((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
           if(len > max) {
              max =len
              copy(longest, line);
            }
    }

    if(max > 0) {
      printf("Longest line is: %s ", longest);
    }`